# Single Quote issue in Formula in PhpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am just inserting formula in a cell using PHPExcel:

```
=INDEX(
   'worksheet_1'!1:1048576,
    MATCH(B2,'worksheet_1'!K:K,0),
    MATCH("CW",'worksheet_1'!A3:BZ3,0)
  )
```

On rendering excel, PHPExcel is giving me below error:

```
worksheet_2!G2 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured
```

Here, I have created another worksheet (worksheet_2) and filling values into this sheet from worksheet_1 using above formula.

After deep debugging, I have found that, single quote(') is creating issue. I have also tried by replace single quote with double quote("). But in this case, formula is not working.

Can anyone please tell me, how can I cop up with this issue?

Comment: Are you really sure that it's the quote causing problems? PHPExcel doesn't really support column or row ranges at all, so I'd suggest that's more likely to be causing problems

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure but as per my analysis after debugging line by line. I have found that in function "_parseFormula()" in file "phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation.php", phpexcel process formula and check operands. So on 2nd iteration, the operand value is single quote(') and no handling for single quote here. As result system  throw error.

Comment: Can you provide an actual working demonstration of that as a bug; because I have a number of tests which work with quoted worksheet names without issue

Comment: Please check this line: $thissheet->setCellValue($letter++ . "" . $row, "=INDEX('worksheet_1'!1:1048576,MATCH(B" . $row . ",'worksheet_1'!K:K,0),MATCH(\"CW\",'worksheet_1'!A3:BZ3,0))"); Code is huge so I can't post here.

Comment: Can you please also check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680493/phpexcel-chart-title-is-showing-as-as-instead-of-name-passed-by-me I am also facing this issue.